# Fetching Column Names From Same Table Where Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I need columns names from table with condition satisfying on the same table.
say if column named 'size' has value '22', while it should check for same value in 24 columns named starting as 'sizecaption1,sizecaption24', and return column names holding the value '22' for each row. Thanks  This is I tried, but it doesnt works for me:

```
create procedure dataaudit()
begin
declare countr  int;
declare headr  int;
set @countr = (select size from joinbom group by stylecode limit 0,1);
set @headr1=(select sizecaption1 from joinbom group by stylecode limit 0,1);
while @countr  = @headr1 do select column_name from 
information_schema.columns where table_name like'joinbom' and 
@countr=@headr;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sparse specification you could try along

```
SELECT
  id,
  TRIM(CONCAT(
    IF(sizecaption1 = size, 'sizecaption1 ', ''),
    IF(sizecaption2 = size, 'sizecaption2 ', ''),
    IF(sizecaption3 = size, 'sizecaption3 ', ''),
    IF(sizecaption4 = size, 'sizecaption4 ', ''),
    IF(sizecaption5 = size, 'sizecaption5 ', ''),
    IF(sizecaption6 = size, 'sizecaption6 ', '')
    )) AS result
FROM JoinBoom
ORDER BY id
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3af0b1/2)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: @user9568504 Could you, please, add a table description and some sample data to your question?